# Reducing a background-image by a percentage of itself not of the parent element

Tags: html, css, background-size

I often use `background images` to display an icon within a rounded square. Sometimes I need to reduce the size of both the square and the icon in it for responsive purposes.

But when I have several icons displayed as `background images` of different sizes, and I want to display all icons, say, 70% their original sizes, I can't just set a `background-size: 70%` because that would mean 70% of the square, whereas what I want is 70% of the `background image` own size.

Any way to achieve that in CSS ?

Comment: Can you please provide us with a fiddle or the html and css? I'd like to help you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the block instead of background image.

```
transform: scale(.7);
```

Comment: Wow it sort of worked. The background images do get reduced as I want. But the surrounding square's border isn't 1px thick anymore so some edges are invisible. Any way to transform without affecting border thickness?

Comment: increasing the border thickness will work ? or is it too thick ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are asking for (70% of the background image itself) then I don't think that's possible with CSS. You could achieve it with JS though. Get the dimensions of the image, calculate what is 70% of those (width * 0.7 and height) and use that to set this as the dimensions of the `background-size:40px 40px;`